# Not able to use default interpeter

Tags: ubuntu, spyder

When setting the interpreter to /usr/bin/python3 I am getting the following error message in Spyder:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
    /usr/bin/python3
doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.4.0 and < 2.5.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by activating your environment first (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
    conda install spyder-kernels=2.4
or
    pip install spyder-kernels==2.4.*
```

When installing with either conda or pip, it says that it's already installed.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Spyder's IPython console [needs the `spyder-kernels` package to be installed](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html#spyder-kernels-version-ref) - that's how Spyder can do stuff like showing you the contents of your variables and so on, AFAIK.

If you really want to run your code from Spyder but in a Python interpreter without spyder-kernels, then as well as changing the Python interpreter go to **Run** in the preferences and select `Execute in a dedicated system terminal`. Now clicking the Run button will open a terminal window to run your code (if you need to see the console output after the code finishes, also select `Interact with the Python console after execution`).

That makes this behaviour the default for all Python files in Spyder, or you can go to **Run > Configuration per file**  to set it separately for each file.